# pg_upgrade --link fails: `directory "/..." already in use as a tablespace`

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm attempting to upgrade from 9.6.2 to 10.5 using `pg_upgrade`

My upgrade command (from OpenBSD pkg-readme):

```
su _postgresql -c "cd /var/postgresql && \
    pg_upgrade --link -b /usr/local/bin/postgresql-9.6/ -B /usr/local/bin \
    -U postgres -d /var/postgresql/data-9.6/ -D /var/postgresql/data"
```

results in the following error

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "mydb" OWNER "mydb" LOCATION '/path/to/postgresql/mydb'; psql:pg_upgrade_dump_globals.sql:87: ERROR:  directory "/path/to/postgresql/mydb/PG_10_201707211" already in use as a tablespace
```

I'm using `--link` because the tablespace mentioned above is using 1.5TB of the available 1.8TB on its partition. So I don't think I'd have the disk space to do pg_upgrade without `--link`

I have disk space on other partitions if that helps.

## EDIT

Before I encountered this error, I ran the`pg_upgrade` command without the `--link` flag, but then killed it when I realized there was insufficient disk space.  After that I re-ran `initdb` followed by the pg_upgrade command above.

Now I have 9.6 running again, but I have two directories in my tablespace location:

```
[root@host:~]$ls /path/to/postgresql/mydb/
PG_10_201707211   PG_9.6_201608131
```

Can I safely rename PG_10_201707211 to PG_9.6_201707211 and try the upgrade again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PG_10_201707211" must be a left over directory from your aborted attempt at running pg_upgrade without the --link flag.  You can delete it, or out of an abundance of caution move it to one of your other partitions.  Renaming it the way you describe wouldn't accomplish much and would be very confusing if you have more problems in the future which require more investigation.

Comment: I think you are correct.  I ended up giving up on pg_upgrade and did a dump-upgrade-load instead, but when I did I encountered a similar error with the PG_10... directory.  I moved to another partition, but didn't end up needing it.